# How to get user details (email and name) using Azure AD auth token?

Tags: spring-boot, access-token, azure-ad-msal

We have a web app that has authentication on the front-end (React JS) using Microsoft OAuth, but no authentication at the back end side (Spring Boot), meaning everybody can access the APIs. We want to secure the APIs using the "Access token" generated by the UI (front-end). The idea is that UI passes the token to the back-end in every API call. Since each API call would contain the token, the back-end will use this to validate which user this token belongs to. Is there a way to achieve this using MSAL?

Tl;dr: How to obtain user details (email and user name) from Microsoft OAuth generated token using MSAL?

I did try going through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview but to no help